# How to detect abnormal point of a lineString

Tags: jts

i have a lineString that could contains abnormal point like this picture.

[image: This picture discribe a line string that contains a point A that does not belong to line]

my Question how can i detect those points is there any Algorithm for that in com.vividsolutions.jts  or any java algo

Answer (score 0):

One of things that sometimes helps to clean up such points is to `buffer` the geometry with a tiny distance.

Buffering extends or shrinks the perimter of the geometry by the specified distance.